# The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value

Tags: sql-server, excel

i am working on importing data from excel to sql server. i am facing problem while i am inserting the date and datetime values in sql server. It is showing me this error:

```
[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException] = {"The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

the date and date time format in excel sheet are in this format:

```
  Date          DateTime
2011-04-26  2011-04-26 13:30
```

What do i have to to do to import these two values to database?

Answer (score 4):

That format will fail if [`set dateformat dmy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx). Make sure you have `set dateformat ymd` or remove the `-` from the dates. `yyyymmdd` will always work.

http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html#YYYYMMDD

Comment: My above problem is solved..What i have done is First i have created a string variable and passed the value to that variable..Then i have created datetime variable and Converted the string variable to datetime and passed that value to the DateTIme variable.